# Change label max length on all field types

Tags: entities

The default max length for all labels of all field types is 128. The db can handle 255. So no schema change. How can I change the default max length to 250?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module and include the hook_form_alter for the content types you want. This is an example of how to do that:

```
function [MODULE_NAME]_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'your_form_id'){
    $form['your_field_name']['label']['#maxlength'] = 255;
  }
}
```

Also you can try this module: http://drupal.org/project/remove_field_label_length_limit